# wxPython: Updating the label on wxStatic causes text to be incorrectly formated

Tags: wxpython

I have a form that uses wxpython, one of the objects on the form displays the users windows logon name.

```
self.stIwpcadmin = wx.StaticText(self.panelLower, -1, "NONE")
```

Of course I don't know what the name is until runtime so I create a wxStatic object with the label of 'NONE', and then at runtime it gets the username and changes the label

```
sUsername = getpass.getuser()
self.stIwpcadmin.SetLabel('WINDOWS/'+sUsername)
```

When this occurs it does update the text of the wxStatic object.  The problem is that it 'runs' into the next object in the GridSizer.  If I adjust the size of the window (any amount, larger or smaller) it forces the object to redraw and it fills in the text correctly.

How can I force this to occur with needing the user to change the window size?

This is the code that shows the sizer data for wxStatic info.  I cut some code out to keep it as brief as possible.  In short self.stIwpcadmin -> grid_sizer_1 -> sizerPassword -> sizerLower -> self.panelLower -> mainSizer

```
def __do_layout(self):
    # begin wxGlade: mainFrame.__do_layout
    mainSizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 1, 0, 0)
    sizerLower = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)
    sizerInstall = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizerInstall_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizerInstallButtons = wx.GridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)
    sizer_4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizerPassword = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizerPassword_staticbox, wx.HORIZONTAL)
    grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(8, 3, 0, 0)
    mainSizer.Add(self.panelUpper, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    grid_sizer_1.Add(self.stIwpcadmin, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 2)
    grid_sizer_1.Add(self.txIwpcadmin, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 2)
    grid_sizer_1.Add(self.btnIwpcadmin, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 2)
    grid_sizer_1.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    grid_sizer_1.Add(self.panel_2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    grid_sizer_1.Add(self.btnValidateAll, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 2)
    sizerPassword.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    sizerLower.Add(sizerPassword, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.panelLower.SetSizer(sizerLower)
    mainSizer.Add(self.panelLower, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
    self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
    mainSizer.Fit(self)
    self.Layout()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force the sizer to redo its layout using the aptly-named [Layout](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html#Layout) method.

Comment: doing self.stIwpcadmin.Layout() did not work.  Neither does .Refresh or several of the other methods I used.  I also tried self.Layout() and self.Refresh()

Comment: Got it.  I have to do the .layout to the parent sizer.  So in this case I had to change grid_sizer_1 to self.grid_sizer_1, and then after I update I do self.grid_sizer_1.layout()